# Short unwanted indentation after figure include

Tags: indentation, includegraphics

I observed a strange small indentation in my text whenever I include a figure and use `\newline`. Here is my code:

```
% ... text before
implemented control architecture.\newline
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{figures/Control/FigName}
    \caption{TBD.}
    \label{control:fig:}
\end{figure}
The main task of each local % text continues
```

As a result I get this:

[image]

I also figured out how to get rid of this unwanted indentation: I have to add `%` signs after the figure include instructions:

```
% ... text before
implemented control architecture.\newline
\begin{figure}%
    \centering%
    \includegraphics{figures/Control/FigName}%
    \caption{TBD.}%
    \label{control:fig:}%
\end{figure}%
The main task of each local % text continues
```

Which gets me what I want:

[image]

This is bugging me not for the first time now and I would like to know how to correctly eliminate this stupid behavior. Why does this happen? And is there a better way of getting rid of it other from going over my whole document and throwing around `%` signs on all the figure include lines?

Comment: Try with just the `%` after `\end{figure}`. Anyway, a picture in the middle of a paragraph is not a floating picture... if the figure is meant to be floating, put them *between* paragraph and be happy. And besides, you shouldn't use `\newline` *ever*...

Comment: What would be the purpose of `\newline`? My impression is that you want a new paragraph, instead.

Comment: Anyway: welcome! If you try to post a simple [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) maybe we can help better. This question smells as an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me...

Comment: I would always recommend inserting images/floats **between** paragraps. Then you never have to bother with things like this.

Comment: What is wrong with \newline? I am not using \par since \par starts the new paragraph with a considerably larger indentation as the one in my post. The behavior of \par is ok, I really want that if I start a new paragraph, but I'm using \newline if I explicitly don't want any indentation but only a new line.

Comment: @FaradayParadox If you're not starting a paragraph, why the `\newline`?

Answer (score 3):

I was wrong. Adding a `\noindent` does not fix the problem. So, let me try again.

You are right. Adding a `\newline` does not start a new paragraph. The extra space in front of the last line of your output is not an indentation. It is indeed a blank space
caused by the end-of-line character after `\end{figure}`.
It is just like the blank space between `every` and `day` created by the end-of-line character following `every`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
every
day
\end{document}
```

To eliminate that blank space, one can do this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
everyday
\end{document}
```

or this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
every%
day
\end{document}
```

That's why adding a `%` right after `\end{figure}` fixes the problem.
Of course, you can also delete that extra space by this

```
% ... text before
implemented control architecture.\newline
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{figures/Control/FigName}%
    \caption{TBD.}
    \label{control:fig:}
\end{figure}The main task of each local % text continues
```

Comment: But if I use \newline at other locations where no figure is included I just get a new paragraph without any indentation. Why does the behavior depend on where I include the figure?

Comment: @FaradayParadox, I revised my answer.